# WPF - how to set the correct DataContext for custom UserControls from DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I am trying to make a custom UserControl (`TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer`) to display an error code and a list of buttons for the user to interact with. In a DataTemplate (`TSFloorPlanInputStationProductDispenserMemberTemplate`), I wish to use two 'instances' of this custom UserControl, but I'm messing up the DataContext but I'm not sure how to set it correctly.

`TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ASC_Control_HMI.TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ASC_Control_HMI"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Name="ucProductDispenserStockViewer"
             >

    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="LightYellow">
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbProductDispenserStockID" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
            <Border x:Name="brdChangeButtons" Background="LightSalmon" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="4,0,4,0" Height="60" BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="4" BorderThickness="1">
                <local:TSRemoteManualControlBar x:Name="DispenserStockManualControlBar" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ManualControlBarActions="{Binding ViewerManualControlBarActions}">

                </local:TSRemoteManualControlBar>
            </Border>
            <Border DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="LightBlue">
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbErrorStock" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ProductDispenserStockError}"/>
            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer.xaml.cs` (extract of):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ProductDispenserStockErrorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ProductDispenserStockError", typeof(string), typeof(TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer.OnProductDispenserStockErrorPropertyChanged)));

private static void OnProductDispenserStockErrorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer control = d as TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer;
    if ((control != null) && (e.NewValue != null))
    {
        //(control.DataContext as TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer).ProductDispenserStockError = Convert.ToString(e.NewValue);
        control.DataContext = e.NewValue;
    }
}

public string ProductDispenserStockError
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(ProductDispenserStockErrorProperty);
    }
    set 
    {
        SetValue(ProductDispenserStockErrorProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewerManualControlBarActionsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ViewerManualControlBarActions", typeof(ObservableCollection<TSRemoteManualControlBarAction>), typeof(TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer),
    new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer.OnManualControlBarActionsPropertyChanged)));

private static void OnManualControlBarActionsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer control = d as TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer;

    if ((control != null) && (e.NewValue != null))
    {
        control.DataContext = e.NewValue;
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<TSRemoteManualControlBarAction> m_ViewerManualControlBarActions;
public ObservableCollection<TSRemoteManualControlBarAction> ViewerManualControlBarActions
{
    get
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<TSRemoteManualControlBarAction>)GetValue(ViewerManualControlBarActionsProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ViewerManualControlBarActionsProperty, value);
    }
}
```

`TSFloorPlanInputStationProductDispenserMemberTemplate.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ASC_Control_HMI"
                    >
    
    <local:BoolToOpacityValueConverter x:Key="IsActiveToOpacity"/>
    <local:BoolToVisibilityValueConverter x:Key="IsActiveToVisibility"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="FloorPlanInputStationProductDispenserMemberTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:TSFloorPlanInputStationProductDispenser}">
        <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource IsActiveToVisibility}}">
            <DockPanel>
                <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                    <Grid x:Name="grdDispenserStockViewers" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                            <!--<RowDefinition Height="*"/>-->
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <local:TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ProductDispenserStockViewer1" ProductDispenserStockID="Upper" ProductDispenserStockError="{Binding UpperStockError}" ViewerManualControlBarActions="{Binding ManualControlBarActions1}">

                        </local:TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer>
                        <local:TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ProductDispenserStockViewer2" ProductDispenserStockID="Lower" ProductDispenserStockError="{Binding LowerStockError}" ViewerManualControlBarActions="{Binding ManualControlBarActions2}">

                        </local:TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </DockPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I'm setting the error strings to "DefaultError" in the constructor of the `TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer` in order to see something at least, but they are printed in the slots reserved for the `ManualControlBar`. I'm pretty sure I've got the DataContext setup wrong, but I am unable to get it right with the other posts I found concerning binding of data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**======= EDIT =======**

I've removed the Viewer's references to the DataContext, as suggested by @bioniccode, and any default values I give to the viewer's properties `ProductDispenserStockError` or `ViewerManualControlBarActions` get displayed. When I try to use the UserControl's parent's properties for these values though, they don't update

```
<local:TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
    x:Name="ProductDispenserStockViewer1"
    ProductDispenserStockID="Upper"
    ProductDispenserStockError="{Binding UpperStockError}"
    ViewerManualControlBarActions="{Binding ManualControlBarActions1}">

</local:TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer>
<local:TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
    x:Name="ProductDispenserStockViewer2"
    ProductDispenserStockID="Lower"
    ProductDispenserStockError="{Binding LowerStockError}"
    ViewerManualControlBarActions="{Binding ManualControlBarActions2}">
```

How do I bind the viewers properties to the properties from the Template's 'code-behind'?

Comment: You are assigning `control.DataContext = e.NewValue;` in a PropertyChangedCallback. This is totally wrong. A control must never set its own DataContext, especially not to the value of one of its bindable properties.

Comment: The DataContext of a control in a DataTemplate is automatically passed from the Content property of the ContentControl or ContentPresenter that applies the DataTemplate. There is no need to set it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the DataContext internally. You never do this. You don't even get the `DataContext`. Your control is able to operate without knowing the `DataContext`.

Internal elements always bind to dependency properties of the custom control (or `UserControl`). Whencreating a `ControlTemplate`you bind using `{TemplateBinding}` or `{Binding RelativeSource={realtiveSource TemplatedParent}}`. In every other case you use `Binding.ElementName` or `Binding.RelativeSource`.

For example

**TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer.xaml.cs**
Remove all references to te DataContext.

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty ProductDispenserStockErrorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "ProductDispenserStockError", 
  typeof(string), 
  typeof(TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer));

public string ProductDispenserStockError
{
  get => (string)GetValue(ProductDispenserStockErrorProperty);
  set => SetValue(ProductDispenserStockErrorProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewerManualControlBarActionsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "ViewerManualControlBarActions", 
  typeof(ObservableCollection<TSRemoteManualControlBarAction>), 
  typeof(TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer));

public ObservableCollection<TSRemoteManualControlBarAction> ViewerManualControlBarActions
{
  get => (ObservableCollection<TSRemoteManualControlBarAction>)GetValue(ViewerManualControlBarActionsProperty);
  set => SetValue(ViewerManualControlBarActionsProperty, value);
}
```

**TSFloorPlanProductDispenserStockViewer.xaml.cs**
Then fix the bindings and bind to directly the dependency properties defined by the `UserControl`.

```xml
<UserControl x:Name="Root">
  <Grid>
    <DockPanel>
 
      <!-- Option #1: Binding.ElementName (recommended) -->
      <local:TSRemoteManualControlBar x:Name="DispenserStockManualControlBar" 
                                      ManualControlBarActions="{Binding ElementName=Root, 
                                                                        Path=ViewerManualControlBarActions}" />

      <!-- Option #2: Binding.RelativeSource -->
      <TextBlock x:Name="tbErrorStock" 
                 Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, 
                                Path=ProductDispenserStockError}"/>
    </DockPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now you can use the control as usual. External DataContext values are no longer overwritten and therefore external bindings set on the control can behave normal.